# Excel vba как выполнить запрос с параметром

Tags: excel, vba

подскажите пожалуйста как в VBA выполнить sql запрос с параметром?

Мой код:

```
Dim dbPath As String
dbPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\База.xlsx"
    
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & dbPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

Conn.Open ConnectionString
Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn

Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [База$] SET Значение=@param WHERE Ид=" & Txt_Id.Text & ""
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, Txt_Name.Text)
Cmd.Execute
```

Получаю ошибку "Слишком мало параметров. Требуется 1."
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Эксел файлы не являются файлами базы данных в данном контексте (хотя хранят данные)
2. Провайдер баз данных SQL подключается к централизованным (MSSQL, MySQL и т.д.) и локальным - базы данных MS Accent.
3. В вашей программе также нужно определить  Conn и Cmd

Что делать:
Перевести (импортировать) базу в Access (синтаксис-пунктуация SQL в Access немного отличается)